Classifying space of finite group as a complex manifold
Suppose $G$ be a finite group. Then, is it always possible to construct a classifying space which is a finite dimensional(if not, possibly infinite dimensional) complex manifold?
More precisely, are there a model of $\mathrm{E} G \to \mathrm{B} G$ such that $\mathrm{E} G$ and $\mathrm{B} G$ are complex manifolds(hence the bundle structure is holomorphic obviously)?
Moreover, If it's possible, then could we extend the story for K"ahler manifold?
of if it's impossible, then what's the obstruction for this?
One of the possible obstruction is : Could some complex(K"alher) manifold have $G$ as its fundamental group. It seems nontrivial, unless it's just a real manifold.
Motivation of the question is building a finite dimensional complex classifying space of permutation group $G = \mathrm{Sym}_n$, but I don't have any background knowledge around this topic.

A finite nontrivial group never acts freely on a contractible finite-dimensional manifold.

For $G$ a finite group, $BG$ is never homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex or manifold. The argument is standard and runs as follows: suppose there were such a finite-dimensional CW complex or manifold $X$ homotopy equivalent to $BG$. Pick any nontrivial cyclic subgroup $C \subset G$. Then there is a corresponding covering space $Y \to X$ inducing the inclusion of $C$ on $\pi_1$, and $Y$ is also a finite-dimensional CW complex or manifold.
But we know the homology and cohomology of the finite cyclic groups, and it's nonzero in arbitrarily high degree; in other words $Y$ is (co)homologically infinite-dimensional, which is a contradiction.
There is a reasonably nice way to write down the classifying spaces $BS_n$ as configuration spaces of $n$ points in an infinite-dimensional vector space, see here.
